# Practical problem involving geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

John has $ 536,238 in the bank at 6% interest rate. He wants to take out what he has saved, in 11 annual portions, the first time at the beginning of the year he turns 60 and the last time at the beginning of the year he turns 70.

How much can he withdraw each year if interest rates is 6% per year throughout the period?

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: John is 60

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\$536,238 = P$ for the sake of clarity, and let $A$ be the amount John must withdraw each year.

At the beginning of year $1$ (age $= 60$), there will be $P-A$ dollars left in the bank.

At the beginning of year $2$ (age $= 61$), there will be $(P-A)(1.06)-A$ dollars left in the bank.

At the beginning of year $3$ (age $= 62$), there will be $(P-A)(1.06)^2-A(1.06)-A$ dollars left in the bank.

Continue in this way to find the expression for the amount left at the beginning of year $11$, you may then equate this to $0$ and solve for $A$.

EDIT:

At the beginning of year $11$ (age $= 70$), there will be

$$
(P-A)(1.06)^{10}-A(1.06)^9-A(1.06)^8 - \cdots - A
$$
dollars left in the bank. We equate this to zero as all the money is gone at this stage:

$$ 
(P-A)(1.06)^{10}-A(1.06)^9-A(1.06)^8 - \cdots - A = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow P(1.06)^{10}-A(1.06)^{10}-A(1.06)^9-A(1.06)^8 - \cdots - A(1.06)^0 = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow P(1.06)^{10}-A[(1.06)^{10}-(1.06)^9-(1.06)^8 - \cdots - (1.06)^0] = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow P(1.06)^{10}-A\left(\frac{1-(1.06)^{11}}{1-1.06}\right) = 0
$$
$$
\Rightarrow A = \$64142.645.
$$

Comment: Hmm that seems like a lot of work. There is supposed to be an easy way to solve it using geometric series. Do you know any faster way?

Comment: Actually, its not much work at all.

Comment: Ok, sorry maybe i misunderstood. But I am supposed to solve it using the following formula: S=a1*((k^n)-1)/(k-) where S is the sum, a1 is the firts withdrawal, k is the growth and n is the total amount of withdrawals

Comment: @Ali Mustafa You could probably do it just by blindly filling out a financial formula, but as you know it is sometimes better to work out the answer for yourself. I have posted up a fairly complete methodology. This was done rather quickly so be sure to go through the steps yourself and see if you get the answer I found.

Comment: Hmm. The right answer is supposed to be 43567$.

Comment: Given the way you have stated the question, that answer cannot be right. Suppose John takes $\$43,567$ out every year for 11 years, then that makes only $\$479,237$ is taken out in total, meaning that there's plenty left in the bank. Does this make sense?

Comment: Ok, I think I should forget this problem, because its just confusing. But thanks for helping me out.